# __isinstance__ of metaclass called in Python 2 but not 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5, metaclass

Take the following code:

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        print('Checking instance')
        return True

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

print(isinstance(1, MyClass))
```

In Python 2.7, the output is

```
checking instance
True
```

In Python 3.5, the output is

```
False
```

This implies the `__instancecheck__` of `MyMeta` is being used in Python 2 but not in Python 3 for whatever reason. The section on `__isinstance__` is the same in the Python [2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) docs, and I haven't been able to find the cause of this difference of behavior. Anyone know why?

Comment: How did you define `MyClass` in python 3? The `__metaclass__ = ...` syntax only works in python 2.

Comment: @Aran-Fey you've got at the answer to the question probably, I used the same code in both.

Comment: The metaclass’s instance check is being called both times, but in 3.x, the metaclass isn’t `MyMeta`, it’s `type`. So that’s why the docs on `__instancecheck__` don’t explain the difference—because the difference is somewhere else, in how you specify a metaclass.

Comment: Thanks @vaultah and @abarnert!